# Build SQL query from logger table

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a logger table with the following fields: timestamp, point_id, value.
An external application is using this table and every time a value of point_id is changing, the application writes a record with the timestamp, point_id and value.

I want to create a query that returns me values of several point_id's (for example - 'point_id='AA1' or point_id='AA2') and their values in a timestamp window ('where timestamp between @start and @end').
Can anyone please help me build an SQL statement to run this query?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute and take the [tour], and read [ask]. Then, please [edit] your question to include a tag for the RDBMS you are using, your sample data as DDL+DML (create table and insert into statements), your desired results and your current attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like the following?

```
DECLARE @startDatetime DATETIME = '2018-03-01 10:00:00'
DECLARE @endDatetime DATETIME = '2018-03-20 12:00:00'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Points') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #Points

CREATE TABLE #Points (point_id VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO #Points (point_id)
VALUES
  ('AA2'), -- your point IDs
  ('A10')

SELECT
  L.point_id,
  L.timestamp,
  L.value
FROM
  LoggerTable AS L
  INNER JOIN #Points AS P ON L.point_id = P.point_id
WHERE
  L.timestamp BETWEEN @startDatetime AND @endDatetime
ORDER BY
  L.point_id,
  L.timestamp
```